# Subquery returned more than 1 value with SQL 2008 but successfully with SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I have excuted store procedure in both SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
DECLARE @mobile varchar(20)
BEGIN
SET @mobile = (select Mobile from NodesMobile where nodeId = 1) //@mobile will return '123;456'
INSERT INTO dbo.SMS([sSub], [sContent]) 
SELECT *,'sms_content' from dbo.splitstring(@mobile)
END
```

in this, SELECT *,'sms_content' from dbo.splitstring(@mobile) will return:

```
Mobile  Content
123     sms_content
456     sms_content
```

In SQL server 2000, it is successfully insert 2 rows to dbo.SMS:

```
Id   sSub     sContent
1    123      sms_content 
2    456      sms_content
```

But it is show error in SQL Server 2008:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression
```

I dont know why???

EDIT: dbo.splitstring is a function for split string by ';'

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit nvarchar(255) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: It's good that you've upgrading off 2000, but 2008 is also completely supported and you should be aiming to get off that too

Comment: thank you, i'm using sql server 2016 but this server is running with 2008 and I can not upgrade it now

Comment: If the answer below produces the error it's your function or a trigger that's the problem.

Comment: @Larnu: thank you, I have found the error in my trigger :(

Answer (score 0):

Your date might be different, try `limit` your `subquery` results.

```
DECLARE @mobile varchar(20)
BEGIN
SET @mobile = (select top 1 Mobile from NodesMobile)
INSERT INTO dbo.SMS([sSub], [sContent]) 
SELECT [Name],'sms_content' from dbo.splitstring(@mobile)
END
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it still show same error. my purpose is create a loop that insert mobile/content to dbo.SMS

Comment: @Kid1412, try again

Comment: @Metal: dbo.splitstring is a function for split string by ";" (same as i have edited post) It is still show error :(

Comment: Why do you want a loop, @kid1412 ? Loops are awful in an RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu: i have build an application that will send SMS automatically when have problem, and I need insert mobile phone numbers of those who will resolve it (about 10-20 numbers)

Comment: everything is successfully when I use sql server 2000, but when I use sql 2008, it show error :(

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need a loop for an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in string_split, but rather in the mobile part:
`SET @mobile = (select Mobile from NodesMobile where nodeId = 1)`

This can never succeed if you have more than one match from NodesMobile table.

This is how it looks on SQL Server 2000:

```sql
select *, 1 as nodeid into nodesmobile
from
(
    select  123, N'sms_content'
    union all select    456, N'sms_content'
) t (Mobile,Content)

SELECT @@version
go
DECLARE @mobile varchar(20)

SET @mobile = (select Mobile from NodesMobile where nodeId = 1)
select @mobile
```

Outputs:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.818 (Intel X86) 
    May 31 2003 16:08:15 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
    Workgroup Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

State: 21000, error code: 512, Line: 4, ProcName:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I'm guessing something else is going on

Comment: per the discussion in the comments the issue was a trigger. Seems like this Q should just be closed as not providing all relevant details to repro